# Reference changed before change of reference

Tags: javascript, foreach, next.js

What I am trying to do is to switch out an object's property (a *string*) with a matching (keyed) object from another object where the values are keyed.

So for example...

```js
const dataRefs = {
  'idkey1': { title: "Key1", /*...etc... */ },
  'idkey2': { title: "Key2", /*...etc... */ },
  'idkey3': { title: "Key3", /*...etc... */ },
  // ...etc...
};

const pages = [
 { title: "A Page", data: 'idkey1' },
 // ...etc...
];
```

Using the below code I want to switch out `pages[n].data` with the matching property in `dataRefs`.  So using a `forEach` on the pages...

```js
pages.forEach(page => page.data = dataRefs[page.data])
```

Doing this results in `page.data` property becoming `undefined`, even though it should match.

If I try to debug by outputting it to console, I get some unusual effect of seeing the undefined *only* when the code is added *after* the output....

```js
// This works and does the match exactly as I want it.
pages.forEach(page => console.log("%s: ", page.data, dataRefs[page.data]));
// Output:
//  idkey1: undefined

// This however results in bizzare behaviour and ends up with "undefined".
pages.forEach(page => {
  // using console.log to see what's going on...
  console.log("%s: ", page.data, dataRefs[page.data]);
  page.data = dataRefs[page.data];
});
// Output:
//  [Object object]: undefined

// Trying this alternative, just in case how the DOM inspector 
// might be using references, but still the same issue...
pages.forEach(page => {
  console.log(page.data + ": ", dataRefs[page.data]);
  page.data = dataRefs[page.data];
});
// Output:
//  [Object object]: undefined
```

Have checked spelling of variables and gone over and over the code trying so many variants but it seems that no matter what I do, calling `page.data = dataRefs[page.data]` does not work.  Would this be some sort of complex race-condition or have I been watching too much Matrix of late?

This is being called in the Component's `render()` method.

Using Safari 14.1.2, if that helps.

Comment: I tried with your example data above, and I got the result `[{"title":"A Page","data":{"title":"Key1"}}]`

Comment: Where do these arrays come from? Are they being created by async functions? My guess is you're trying to process them before the async functions have completed.

Comment: Have just done some more testing using the debugging and noticed that having the assignment line results in the data changed before the forEach() is called!! commenting out the assignment line and it's not changed before the forEach(). Using a brakepoint only breaks after the whole array has been updated. This is built on nextjs (in the `render()` method).  Have a feeling that something is being prerendered  before the function is called.  Feeling like I'm watching Tenent in my code.   Ended up putting `if (page.data instanceof Object) return;` before assignment to stop it from calling twice.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar, the code in the question is the best example, and I have a feeling that it won't reproduce due to the NextJS framework causing it, as this sort of pattern has never been a problem on other projects, just this one.

Comment: If it's a Next.js issue then it will be reproducible in Next.js. Providing the full code of the component where this is used would help us identify the issue. Also, keep in mind that [Next.js pre-renders every page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) on the server, which could be related to what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related with Next.JS.  Best guess is that Next.JS was pre-rendering the data, storing it in some JSON cache file and passing that to the component render function....or something like that.

Using the browser's inspector, a breakpoint at the problematic line `page.data = dataRefs[page.data]` was only ever triggered once, and showed the data had already been manipulated by the function, before it had been called.  Which is simply odd.  Removing the line, the breakpoint would trigger and the data not converted.

This leads me to believe it to be some sort of NextJS pre-lifecycle thing, possibly as part of the SSG process.

To resolve the issue and move on, I used a check `if (page.data instanceof Object) return;` to stop it from running twice, which seemed to do the trick.  Not ideal, but without a better reason, this will have to suffice.  So the code ultimately went like....

```js
pages.forEach(page => {
   // skip the loop if the data has already been converted
   //   could have also used a string check, but both should work for now.
   if (page.data instanceof Object) return;

   // now change the data if it's still a string referrence
   page.data = dataRefs[page.data]));
});
```

Again, appologies that I don't have the best answer, but this was the only way to resolve it, and since Javascript does not do this normally (have done this sort of thing so many times without issue), it will have to be chalked up to a NextJS/SSG (or some other processor) issue.

Would love to get any NextJS expert's knowledge on how this could happen.